# How pass Map<String, Object> to method with parameter Class<T>

Tags: java

I have method with the following signature:

```
public <T> T get(final Object key, final Class<T> clazz)
```

As `clazz` I need to pass `Map<String, Object>` but I can not do something like `Map<String, Object> data = get("key", Map<String, Object>.class)`. If I call this method as `Map<String, Object> data = get("key", Map.class)` I will get warning.

What is the best solution in this case?

Comment: The class itself is not generic, only instances of this class are. Furthermore, due to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), the type-information are not longer present at runtime.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: Check com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken<T> from Gava library

Comment: The best solution is to realize that there is no way to avoid a warning.